# remote:Permission denied when pushing to github

Tags: git, github

I had two github accounts with username samwelnm2022 and mchomvus4, I have a work to push to username mchomvus4 but when i try to push from git, i get an error message

```
remote: Permission to myRepositoryname.git denied to samwelnm2022.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myRepositoryname.git/': The requested URL 

returned error: 403
```

I tried to push the work with github Desktop and it work fine

Anyone who can help me please

Answer (score 0):

Using the wrong username means the credential caching (`git config credential.helper`) has cached the credentials for samwelnm2022 associated to `github.com`.

If you need, for that one push, to do so with a different account, try:

```
git push https://mchomvus4@github.com/<me>/<myRepo> master
```

That will force using a different GitHub user account for that specific push.

Comment: should i write mchomvus4 in<me>

Comment: @mchomvu Yes, if you are pushing to a repository owned by that account.

Comment: "https://mchomvus4@github.com/mchomvus4/nottech-lab/python-101.git/ master" I get and error that remote:Not found

Comment: " git push https://mchomvus4@github.com/mchomvus4/nottech-lab/python-101.git/ master" i get and error remote: Not found

Comment: @mchomvu Yes, a proper GitHub URL is `https://<user>@github.com/<user>/<repo>`, not `https://<user>@github.com/<user>/folder/<repo>`. In your case: `https://github.com/mchomvus4/python-101/`